# Determine size of image downloaded like in network tab

Tags: javascript, progress-bar, progress

Is it possible to determine dynamically the size of the image downloaded when requested in javascript? It is like when shown in the network bar of inspect option.

Attached the screenshot.
Here the status is 200 and the size 1.3 MB is downloaded and counting. Actual size is 4.2 MB.
Is it possible to display in UI that -- Loading 1.3 MB / 4.2 MB...

where 1.3 MB is counting.
Help would be appreciated[image]

Comment: `when requested in javascript?` Do you mean a direct Javascript request for the resource, or something like setting the `src` of an image element in the HTML?

Comment: requested actually from javascript